# How can I make sure that all the spawned threads are done so that processing can continue?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have a `ConcurrentMap` and I put elements from an `ArrayList` to the map for other threads to process. Once a thread finishes its processing it adds the result in the `ConcurrentMap` and calls a method in order for let's say the "main" thread to get and process all the results (from both the `ConcurrentMap` and the `ArrayList`).
This approach works but has a result to call the method as many times as the number of elements in the list.
**Question:** What constructs can I use so that the method is called once, after the `ConcurrentMap` is fully populated by the results of all background threads?

Comment: Can't you just call join() on the other Threads?

Comment: @KevinWorkman:The threads are spawned by other constructs out of my control. Basically they are encapsulated in other objects and I can only start one for a task. I don't have access/start any thread

Comment: Do you know how many Objects will end up in the ConcurrentMap? Do you know when an item has been added? This would be easier to talk about if you posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)- the processing can just be a call to Thread.sleep() or something.

Comment: @KevinWorkman:If the `ArrayList` has N elements that is the number that will be in the map

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountDownLatch` initialize it with total items in Arraylist and every time a item in process count it down using `countDown` method,

Main thread can call `await` method on latch, await blocks the thread till counter reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do this

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Value> map = ...
listToProcess.parallelStream().forEach(e -> addElementToMap(e, map));
```

This will perform the processing of all the element using all the CPUs you have and only return when they are all done.

Comment: Ah. Sorry I am in Java 7 and can't upgrade. Thanks for the snippet though

Comment: @Jim in that case, add all the tasks to an ExecutorService, save all the Futures in a list and then wait for them all to complete.